# When i give ant fresh_install it gives error PostgreSQL 'pgcrypto' extension installed /up to date? False (not installed) Create extension pgcrypto

Tags: dspace

When i give ant fresh_install it gives error PostgreSQL 'pgcrypto' extension 
installed /up to date? False (not installed) 
Create extension pgcrypto﻿[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOjgJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

See the following upgrade instructions for DSpace: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Upgrading+DSpace#UpgradingDSpace-UpgradeSteps

```
# Login to your "dspace" database as a superuser
psql --username=postgres dspace
# Enable the pgcrypto extension on this database
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```